# Different kinds of marbles

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, combinations

Ben Chusey walks into a marble store wanting to buy 12 marbles for his kid. The store has red, blue, green, yellow, and orange marbles.
How many different kinds of marbles can he select?
How many different kinds of marbles can he select which he has at least one of each kind?

I dont understand this problem because im choosing 12 from 5. It's combinations with repetition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula for combinations with replacement is

$\frac{(n + r - 1)!}{r!(n - 1)!}$

$\frac{(5 + 12 - 1)!}{12!(5 - 1)!} = 1820$

Part 2

$\frac{(5 + 7 - 1)!}{7!(5 - 1)!} = 330$

Answer (score 0):

Ben has to collect 12 marbles and each marble can be of 5 different colors. So the number of ways he can do so is $5^{12}$.

When you impose the restriction that there should be at least one of each kind, then first you select $5$ marbles with the $5$ different colors, and again the remaining $7$ marbles he can choose as before, that is in $5^7$ ways.

Comment: But this isn't permutations this is combinations.... The order does not matter. Probably I should change the title